# How to know what item is chosen from array using random library?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a bot that asks a person s basic true/false questions. I have two `.txt` files (one with questions and one with answers) which I open then read and remove the new line character `'\n'` from. This is my code for reading the questions file:

```
import random

engine = pyttsx3.init()

with open('read_ques.txt', 'r') as file:
    data_ques = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    data1 = data_ques.split('? ')

random_ques = random.choice(data1)

print(random_ques)
```

The problem is that I don't know what question `random.choice()` will choose from the questions `.txt` file, so I can't tell if the person was correct about if the answer was true or false.

Here are a few lines from each of my files.

Questions file:

```
Chameleons have extremely long tongues sometimes as long as their bodies, True or False?
An ostrichs eye is bigger than its brain, True or False?
A sneeze is faster than the blink of an eye, True or False?.
Pigs can look up into the sky, True or False?
```

Answers file:

```
Answer: True.
Answer: True.
Answer: True.
Answers: False (They cannot).
```

line 1 question(in questions file) = line 1 answer(in answers file)

line 2 question(in questions file) = line 2 answer(in answers file)
etc.

Comment: `random_ques` is the question that was chosen, what difficulty are you having comparing that to the converted speech? or is your problem, that the text file doesn't contain the answer to that question? because it should, you should have both the question and the answer in the text file

Comment: Get a random number instead (between 0 and the amount of questions) and get the text and answer using that index.

Comment: @Jeppe why use index and access the list by that index? `random.choice` does that already

Comment: @Matiiss How can you know which answer belongs to the question provided by random.choice? He has two sources where he needs a common random index (as I understand the question).

Comment: For example, if the question was are there a hundred cents in a dollar and the user said true. How would I know that the person was right if I don't even know what the question was because there are a thousand questions in the .txt file and random.choice() chooses anyone without me knowing which one. So, my question is how do you know what question random.choices() chooses.

Comment: @Jeppe as I understand there seems to be no source of the answer (which btw should be contained in the same file anyways), also your method is great for memory management, since there is no need to read the entire file in the memory, just iterate over that file until the chosen line

Comment: @jjoa you need to have the answers in that file as well

Comment: @Matiiss how do I differentiate between a question and answer if they are in the same file?

Comment: Create your own schema: e.g. each line has "Q: [question text] A: [true/false]" -- it may be worth using JSON for this rather than plain text.

Comment: have a structure sth like this (a lot of different ways to do this really) `question? answer\n` (obvs in the text editor you wouldn't see the newline char but you would have the cursor in a new line) and so you can split the file text by `'\n'` to get all the answers and questions, then when `choice` chooses one of those pairs, split that pair by `'? '` and first item will be the question and second item will be the answer

Comment: @Matiiss I will try that

Comment: @Matiiss I still don't understand what you mean by then when `choice` chooses one of those pairs, split that pair by  `'? '` and first item will be the question and second item will be the answer. How should I do that? Thanks for all your time.

Comment: I am gonna assume that you already got a list with strings that contain the question and the answer, sth like this: `data = ['question? answer', 'question? answer']` (except you probably would have sth like `data = file.read().split('\n')`) so now when `choice` chooses: `random_question = random.choice(data)`, you can unpack the question and the answer: `question, answer = random_question.split('? ')` and so you can ask the user the `question` and compare their answer with `answer` (sth like `if user_answer == answer: print('correct answer')`)

Comment: I think you need to show us a few lines from your files. Your question mentions one file for questions and one for answers. My assumption is then that line-number identifies a question in one file, and the corresponding answer in the other file. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jeppe that is correct but what Matiiss said above could also work but I will add questions and answers from each file above in the post. Hopefully what you think will also work.

Comment: I added an answer. I think if you change the input file as suggested, then this question no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since line numbers correlate questions and answers in the two files, I would generate a random line-number and use that to index a random question and its corresponding answer.

```
import random

with open('questions.txt', 'r') as file:
    questions = file.read().split('\n')

with open('answers.txt', 'r') as file:
    answers = file.read().split('\n')


random_idx = random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)

question = questions[random_idx]
answer = answers[random_idx]
```

Comment: Great answer! The program works for quite a long time till I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/talk_bot/hello.py", line 13, in <module> question = questions[random_idx] IndexError: list index out of range` I added the following code `print(question)  if input("What is the answer? ").lower().startswith(answer): print("Right answer") else: print("Wrong Answer")` in a while true loop and also put the `random_idx`, `question`, `answer` variables in the loop as well. Any ideas what is happening.

Comment: @jjoa I updated the answer so that it is now `random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)`. I forgot this function was inclusive. You should also check that your lists of questions and answers are of equal length.